# Javascript/VUE2: How to check value for multiple matches,

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, vuejs2

I am trying to make a full house combination in the game of Yahtzee. (3 of the same dice and 2 of the same)

I have a function that count occurences and will output in here after the random dice generator function:

```
   countDice:      {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0},
```

I want to check if the value has a 3 and a 2. And then return 25. I tried to access it with Object.values and some other ways with loops and etc. I tried it with filter but that seems to only work on an object in array and then the rest of my code messes up.

I have tried this as last :

```
 function has(obj, value) {
                    for(var value in obj) {
                        if(this.countDice.value === 3 this.countDice.value === 2 ) {
                        return 25;
                        }
                    }
```

Nothing happens. I have been messing around with every, and some. I am stuck on a simple thing here it seems :s can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Shortest one:

```
return [2,3].every(x => Object.values(this.countDice).includes(x)) ? 25 : null;
```

And from your question, if you are using VueJS would be:

```
data(){
    return {
        countDice:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0},
    }
},
methods:{
    checkCountDice(){
        return [2,3].every(x => Object.values(this.countDice).includes(x)) ? 25 : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly reference the countDice dictionary and check if both 2 and 3 have non-zero values

```js
let countDice = {1: 0, 2: 9, 3: 7, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0};
let isPresent = countDice[2] && countDice[3];
console.log(Boolean(isPresent));
if (isPresent) {
// Your logic goes here
}
```